# Higher Chow groups: a basic case

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Let $Y$ be a smooth irreducible variety over a field $k$. I know that $\mathcal{O}_Y^\times$, the group of invertible functions on $Y$, embeds in the higher Chow group $\mathrm{CH}^1(Y,1)$ [or the first graded piece of $K_1(Y)$]. Is this always an isomorphism? I know it is when $Y=\mathrm{Spec}(k)$.

If it is always an isomorphism, can you provide a reference? If it is not, can you provide a counterexample?

Answer (score 2):

See the precise statement in Corollary 4.2 and Theorem 19.1 in [Mazza-Voevodsky-Weibel. Lecture notes on Motivic Cohomology](http://www.claymath.org/library/monographs/cmim02.pdf).